# Uppercase multiple matches in a REGEXP_REPLACE in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to uppercase strings that match a regular expression.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(
'I am testing this string',
    '(testing|string)',
    UPPER('\\1')
);
```

which does not work, my guess is because the upper is applied to '\1' before it is actually turned into the first capturing group.

Second try:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(
'I am testing this string',
    '(testing|string)',
    UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT('I am testing this string', '(testing|string)'))
);
```

But this time it only applies upper to the first match of REGEXP_EXTRACT.

Desired output: *I am TESTING this STRING*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function cap_matches(text string, match string) returns string language js as r"""
  return text.replace(RegExp(match, 'gi'), word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
""";
select 'I am testing this string' text,  
  cap_matches('I am testing this string', 'testing|string') new_text
```

with output

[image]

or even easier if you want to capitalize whole matched word

```
create temp function cap_matches(text string, match string) 
returns string language js as r"""
  return text.replace(RegExp(match, 'gi'), word => word.toUpperCase());
""";
select 'I am testing this string' text,  
  cap_matches('I am testing this string', 'testing|string') new_text
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression in BigQuery do not support modifing the output via functions such as upper. There are workarounds. First you can replace each word by the upper WORD: `replace(replace("word for text ","word","WORD"),"text,"TEXT)`.

Another approach is to mask the part of the text, which shall be upper cased. Think of markdown language. Everything between two `*` will be capitalized. You can change this character to any other or an combination. The `REGEXP_REPLACE` searches for the parts and adds `*` around the matches. This string is splitted at each `*` and unnested to variable `X` with an `offset` variable. If the offset is odd, the text `X` has capitalized by `UPPER`. The ``` string_agg``concats all parts of the splitted string. The ``` ((SELECT ...))`inside the main`Select` is needed to run the query in a query.

```sql
Select
123 as id,
((SELECT string_agg(if(mod(Offset,2)=1,Upper(x),x),"") from
unnest(split(REGEXP_REPLACE(
'I am testing this string as best as I can do!',
    '(testing|string)',
    '*\\1*'
),"*")) X with offset))
```