# Manipulate the matched value in BigQuery REGEXP_REPLACE and use to replace the value

Tags: json, google-bigquery, timestamp, regexp-replace

I am trying to use the big-query string functions to manipulate JSON (saved as string as it has been streamed from firestore to big-query), and replace an EPOCH timestamp in seconds with the timestamp as a string.

The number of timestamps in the data can vary within each JSON so it's not possible to do this as a sequence of replaces, I need to do this all at once based on a variable number of timestamps.

An example value:

```
{
    "createdAtTimestamp": {
        "_seconds": 1670337132,
        "_nanoseconds": 863000000
    },
    "phoneNo": "+44970000000",
    "phoneVerified": false,
    "updatedAtTimestamp": {
        "_seconds": 1672754379,
        "_nanoseconds": 112000000
    },
    "timestamp3": {
        "_seconds": 1669127206,
        "_nanoseconds": 112000000
    },
    "timestamp4": {
        "_seconds": 1672909833,
        "_nanoseconds": 112000000
    },
    "PIN": "$2b$10$gsgfdgfsdfdf"
}
```

I am close, I am able to run this:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(data,ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data,'"_seconds":([0-9]+)'),'|'),'\\0')
FROM 
  `tableXYZ`
```

So something like the following should work:

```
SELECT
,REGEXP_REPLACE(data,ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data,'"_seconds":([0-9]+)'),'|'),cast(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%X",TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(cast('\\0' as bigint))) as string) )
```

But this throws an error and I can't find a way to manipulate the value that the regex matched (i.e. \0)

Does anyone know how this might be possible, if at all, in big query SQL?

Thanks

Comment: The regex in BigQuery does not allow to use a function to manipulate the output.

Comment: Working with the raw text is never a good idea. You can try use the JSON functions https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions or you can try to create a custom js function that will simplify the regex extraction and replace as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74487759/uppercase-multiple-matches-in-a-regexp-replace-in-bigquery

Answer (score 1):

As Tonion told, JSON functions would be better as to perform operations on a string text.

But it is possible to transform the time from second to a datetime:

```sql
create temp function replace_json_seconds(s string, match string)
returns string
language js as 
"""
function replacer(match, a,secs, offset, string) {
  var d=new Date(new Date(secs * 1000));
  return a+'"'+d.toISOString().slice(0,-1)+'"';
}
return s.replace(RegExp('("'+match+'":) ([0-9]+)*', 'gi') , replacer );
//
""";

With tbl as (select

"""
{
    "createdAtTimestamp": {
        "_seconds": 1670337132,
        "_nanoseconds": 863000000
    },
    "phoneNo": "+44970000000",
    "phoneVerified": false,
    "updatedAtTimestamp": {
        "_seconds": 1672754379,
        "_nanoseconds": 112000000
    },
    "timestamp3": {
        "_seconds": 1669127206,
        "_nanoseconds": 112000000
    },
    "timestamp4": {
        "_seconds": 1672909833,
        "_nanoseconds": 112000000
    },
    "PIN": "$2b$10$gsgfdgfsdfdf"
}

""" data

)

select *,replace_json_seconds(data,"_seconds" ),


 from tbl
```